# Convert Iff statement version 1 to version 4 or 5 in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Can someone help me convert this to a newer pine script?  version. 4 or 5  for some reason i tried different syntax and can't get it to work.  Thanks in advance

```
pos = iff(signal < macd , 1,
        iff(signal > macd, -1, nz(pos[1], 0)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [ternary operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#removed-iff-and-offset).

```
var pos = 0
pos := (signal < macd) ? 1 : (signal > macd) ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)
```